# Wmic process call in for loop doesn't start the cmd

Tags: java, batch-file, wmic

I am trying to retrieve the ProcessID of a Java app launched through a batch file. The problem is that the application does not start.

My code:

```
set cmd=java -jar XXXXXXX.jar XXXXXX.yml
for /f "tokens=2 delims==; " %%a in (' wmic process call create "%cmd%" ^| find "ProcessId" ') do set PID=%%a
start cmd /k echo %pid%
PAUSE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Batch files are pretty picky with whitespace.

Change this:

```
set cmd = java -jar XXXXXXX.jar XXXXXX.yml
```

To this:

```
set cmd=java -jar XXXXXXX.jar XXXXXX.yml
```

This works:

```
set cmd=notepad

for /f "tokens=2 delims==; " %%a in (' wmic process call create "%cmd%" ^| find "ProcessId" ') do set PID=%%a

start cmd /k echo %pid%

PAUSE
```

There may be something wrong with your jar file or perhaps java is not on your PATH.  Try running your command directly at a command prompt to see if it works:

```
c:\>java -jar XXXXXXX.jar XXXXXX.yml
```

Also make sure that you use the full path to your jar file in your cmd otherwise the path will be relative to your system folder:

```
set cmd=java -jar c:\yourpath\XXXXXXX.jar XXXXXX.yml
```

Comment: I already had that in my batch file, I entered those spaces while typing my answer here. I just modified that typo. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @MThi, so is it working now?  If you change "java -jar XXXXXXX.jar XXXXXX.yml" to "notepad" does it work as you expect?  If you just type java -jar XXXXXXX.jar XXXXXX.yml at a command prompt does that work?

Comment: It does work with notepad too for me. Running my java app command alone also works. but The wmic with the java app still does not launch the java app.